# Independent menus in

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have a Master-Detail Activity with two fragments: "A"(master) and "B"(detail), each one with its own menu options in their own toolbars. B uses CoordinatorLayout with that Material Design effect.

How can I put different menu in each toolbar? Every time I ask to inflate, they duplicate the menus in both fragments. i.e. A haves 1 and 2. B have 3 and 4. After fragments creation, A haves 1,2,3,4 and B haves 1,2,3,4. See the problem:

[image: Whats happening now]

I want to put the search and tag icon in the left fragment's toolbar and the phone and mail icon in the right fragment's toolbar.

Comment: Do you have code? Please post the relevant parts. Also, it's a little hard to understand what is going on, try posting a picture of the layout issue.

Comment: @isUserAGoat Loved your username. ahaha just updated with the layout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments have their own way of telling the activity they have their own Options Menu, so when you decide if you should display both fragments side by side in Master, Detail fashion pass an extra telling the Fragment to use its menu then do:

1. just have each fragment call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` which tells the Activity to call `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater)`.
2. in each fragment Override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater)` and handle clicks of those in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)`

otherwise use `setHasOptionsMenu(false)`, when Master Detail is not being used, and inflate the menu using each Activity that hosts the Master or Detail Fragments